# /sys/devices/virtual/gpio this path not found in my PI

Tags: rpi.gpio, node.js

`/sys/devices/virtual/gpio`

this path not found in my Pi, how i can do for access with : `nodejs require('pi-gpio')`

Comment: Which distribution are you using (Raspbian, Fedora, Arch, Risc OS etc)?  Are you a member of the gpio group (sudo adduser your-name gpio)?  What does ls -l /sys/devices/virtual report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to install Raspbian and get approximately these results:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

after that, try to do:

```
$ ls /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/
gpiochip0
```

should work.